# Incorrect filename of the downloaded file in "View Download" Window of IE9

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-9

I had created a website in which when I click on a link button, a small popup window is opened. That popup window has a button, when this button is clicked, a zip file get downloaded to client machine. After downloading the zip file and closing the popup window, If I delete "Download History" using Ctrl+Shift+Del in Internet Explorer 9 and then open the same popup window to download the zip file again, the downloaded zip file is renamed to the aspx page(popup page) name in "View Download" window.

It works fine, if I restart the Browser(IE9) after deleting "Download History" using Ctrl+Shift+Del

Note: The Width of the popup is only 70 pixels

```
FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream("TestFolder.zip", FileMode.Open);
long FileSize = myFileStream.Length;
byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize];
myFileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)FileSize);
myFileStream.Close();

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = @"application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= TestFolder.zip");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", Buffer.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

just an assumption but i guess the issue is(was?) the space between "filename= TestFolder.zip". At least at our place we remove spaces from filenames because it chops off after spaces.